# Help calculating a riemann sum

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

Hello i have this calculus problem but i cannot solve it as i don't understand very much about riemann sums.

Use regular partitions to find the aproximate value of the integral :
$$ \int_{\pi/12}^{\pi/6} \frac12sin(3x)dx $$

for the integration interval use circunscrit rectangles and 3 partitions

... i don't know if i need to make n = 3 as the problem says to use 3 partitions and i don't know how to solve a sum with a sine function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you would obtain for your integral a Riemann-sum as follows:

$$
\int_{\frac{\pi}{12}}^\frac{\pi}{6}\frac{\sin (3x)}{2}\,\mathrm dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\pi}{24n}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{k\pi}{4 n}\right)
$$
Now you're asked explicitly to compute the sum whenever $n=3$:

$$
\sum_{k=1}^3\frac{\pi}{72}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{k\pi}{12}\right)
$$

Note that
$$\begin{aligned}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{12}\right)&=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{6}\right)&=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt 2}\\
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)&=1\end{aligned}$$
Now you have all the ingredients to compute the sum.

Comment: Thank you very much, i understand the problem now and the result i got from the sum was the one i needed.